# introducig changes in style by jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

i've created simple code that should set/change image background depending on window width

```
var backgroundBig = "url(../img/logo1.svg)";
var backgroundSmall = "url(../img/logo2.svg)";
function logoBG(){

    var windowWidth = $(window).width();

    if (windowWidth < 700){

        $("#wrapper1").css({"background-image": backgroundSmall});

    } else {

        $("#wrapper1").css({"background-image": backgroundBig});

    };

};

logoBG();
$(window).resize(logoBG);
```

as simple as that...
optional background image proprieties are set in css file

```
#wrapper1{

background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-size: cover;}
```

everything works fine **in website code** - when i'm tracking changes by firebug, code changes as it should. however, images don't load, nothing changes regarding website display. what is wrong with that?

thanks in advance
PM

Comment: Why not using CSS media queries instead? Or at least toggling a class for background-image.

Comment: Please, provide jsfiddle.

Comment: @A.Wolff yes, changing a class is the remedy :) nevertheless I'm still curious why the proper changes in code introduced by my jQuery script didn't change image display. the path to the image files was correct.

Answer (score 1):

Try this https://jsfiddle.net/2Lzo9vfc/23/

**JS**

```
var backgroundBig = "url(http://placehold.it/1980x960)";
var backgroundSmall = "url(http://placehold.it/1980x960/000000)";
function logoBG(){

    var windowWidth = $(window).width();

    if (windowWidth <= 700){

        $("#wrapper1").css("background-image", backgroundSmall);

    } else {

        $("#wrapper1").css("background-image", backgroundBig);

    };

};

logoBG();
$(window).resize(logoBG);
$(document).ready(logoBG);
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="wrapper1">Lorem</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Because the images must be loaded FIRST, why it's working with firebug ? it's surely because firebug reload the DOM so he can parse it, and when he do so, the images are already loaded.

I can recommend you [jquery.waitForImages](https://github.com/alexanderdickson/waitForImages) because it can even wait for images background, so your JavaScript code is not executed before your images are loaded, and you dont need to Reload the DOM too.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for all advices. The problem with my code was... the paths to my image files.

```
url(../img/logo1.svg)
```

works in css file, that's why I assumed that it's must be correct, but

```
url(img/logobg.svg)
```

should be inserted by the jQuery script. What a lame mistake :)